# Use config variables in templates?

Tags: templates, config

Is there a place in EE to store custom config variables and access them in the templates? I need to be able to use these variables in conditionals as well as output them. Furthermore, I need to have different sets of config values depending on which domain EE is on (e.g. if site_url = 'foo.com' ...).

Currently, I'm using globals, but it's not really ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by config variables, you mean the ones on `config.php`, it's pretty easy to do.

On your `config.php` add the following code:

```
global $assign_to_config;
if(!isset($assign_to_config['global_vars']))
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array();
```

Now, you can create early parsed template variables.

Let's say you set the [mail protocol used by a System Config Override](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#mail-protocol):

```
$config['mail_protocol'] = 'sendmail';
```

If you need to access this info on templates, you need to create a template variable:

```
$config['mail_protocol'] =
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['cv-mail_protocol'] = 'sendmail';
```

On templates, you can use `{cv-mail_protocol}`:

```
{if cv-mail_protocol == 'sendmail'}
  The emails are being send by SendMail
{/if}
```

You can use a PHP conditional too to set them:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'www.domain.com')
```

These variables are parsed even before [Preload Text Replacements](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/preload_replacement.html), which gives you a lot of flexibility.

```
{if cv-language == "en"}
    {preload_replace:pr-name_label="Name"}
    {preload_replace:pr-tel_label="Phone number"}
[...]
{/if}

<label for="name">{pr-name_label}
  <input type="text" id="name" name="required[]" size="50" />
</label>
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to use these config variables in embeds? For example, `{embed="common/.footer-{cv_layout-footer}"}`?

Comment: Sure! Config variables are parsed earlier than the `embed`s. But maybe you should use an `layout`. Try to keep everything simple.

Comment: What do you mean "use an `layout`"?

Comment: Instead of have multiples footers and header, you can use [layouts](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/layouts.html). Of course, I don't know your situation or your code. I'm guessing and trying to suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use index.php for this.

On about line 72 you can add Custom Config Variables as an associative array.

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array('pv_country_id' => 3);
```

You can now use this in your template as `{pv_country_id}` (I prefix with pv_ so I can identify them when I view my templates in the future.)

The reason I use this method is that if you're a MSM user ('Multi Site Manager' for the uninitiated) you can override your variables on a per site basis.

Comment: I never remember I can use the `index.php`, because I prefer to keep everything in one single file. But I think you can update my answer by adding yours.